# While reading XML document node elements number of rows differs during run time

Tags: sql, xml

I have a XML document which is being sent through Pega-Agent. My stored procedure receives the XML and reads the elements.

When I trigger stored procedure manually, 50 rows get affected, however when triggered using Pega-Agent it affects only 11 rows. I tried capturing the XML in a log table and verifying it. Pega-Agent is sending records properly. It is not an upstream issue. It is definitely an issue with SQL Server. But SQL `sp` when I ran using `exec sp sp_name` it affects 50 rows.

Is it problem with the account? Is it possible to restrict a user to access only 11 rows from table?

Comment: can we restrict a user to access only 11 rows from XML document?

Comment: Please show the code of your SP. The information provided is not enough even to guess...

Comment: I got the answer. The code was fine. But the upstream application Pega was limiting the records while sending command to DB. The limitation value was 10. Though it does not send it as parameter but still the configurable value impacts the stored procedure execution. We have modified the Limitation value to max. Now it is yielding results.

Comment: Okay, that's a bit weird... Glad that you found a solution!